Second derivative for $-\ln(-f(\vec{x}))$
According to Approach0 or this, this question is new.
I am doing a past exam paper with no solutions, then I am stuck at the following step:
Let $g=-\ln(-f(\vec{x})):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, where $f(\vec{x})<0$, I want to find $\nabla^2g$.
My attempt:
$$\begin{align}
\nabla g&=\frac{1}{-f(\vec{x})}\nabla f(\vec{x})\\
\implies\nabla^2g&=\frac{\nabla^2 f(\vec{x})(-f(\vec{x}))+\nabla f(\vec{x})\cdot\nabla f(\vec{x})}{(-f(\vec{x}))^2}
\end{align}$$ However, I instantly notice a problem $\nabla^2f(\vec{x})$ is a matrix, however $\nabla f(\vec{x})\cdot\nabla f(\vec{x})$ is a constant, where did I make the mistake?
Thanks a lot!

The product rule for the gradient of a scalar and a vector field is given by
$\nabla(\phi\mathbf{A}) = (\nabla\phi)\mathbf{A}^T + \phi\nabla\mathbf{A}$, with $\phi = -1/f$ and $\mathbf{A} = \nabla f$ in the present case, hence
$$
\nabla(-\ln(-f)) = \nabla\left(-\frac{1}{f}\right) \cdot (\nabla f)^T - \frac{1}{f}\nabla^2f = \frac{(\nabla f)(\nabla f)^T - f\nabla^2f}{f^2}
$$
in the end. Note that you may reinterprete the "reversed" matrix product $(\nabla f)(\nabla f)^T$ as the tensorial product $\nabla f \otimes \nabla f$.

First you should consider what you want to compute. This is already ambiguous in the first derivative, as $f'(\vec x)$ is a row vector while the gradient $\nabla f(\vec x)$ is a column vector (that is formally obtained via the scalar product, but which is trivial in the Euclidean case).
The second derivative $f''(\vec x)$ is a symmetric bilinear form. As that has a 2-dimensional array of coefficients, one likes to read it as matrix, the Hesse matrix. What you chose to write, $\nabla^2 f(\vec x)$, is the double gradient, which lives in the tensor product of the column space of $\vec x$ with itself.
So in the basic case of the second derivative as a bilinear form (with dummy arguments $v,w$)
$$
(-\ln(-f(\vec x)))''[v,w]=\left(-\frac{f'(\vec x)[v]}{f(\vec x)}\right)'[w]
=-\frac{f''(\vec x)[v,w]}{f(\vec x)}+\frac{f'(\vec x)[v]f'(\vec x)[w]}{f(\vec x)^2}.
$$
It should be clearly visible that in the translation to the other two forms, the last term is an outer product or a tensor product, not an inner/scalar product.
$$
\nabla^2(-\ln(-f))=-\frac{\nabla^2 f}{f}+\frac{\nabla f\otimes \nabla f}{f^2}
$$
etc.
